# Attach network interface device to ec2 instance AWS via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to attach network interface device in Terraform. I have tried testing with the code below but when creating an instance, AWS already makes an eni, before you attach anything.

So when you attach something, you will end up with a second eni. I need only one primary private IP and it results in 2 private IPs.

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "test" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public_a.id}"
  private_ips = ["10.0.0.50"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.web.id}"]
  attachment {
    instance = "${aws_instance.test.id}"
    device_index = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that would be to use the `network_interface` argument in terraform when creating the EC2 instance. Your terraform template should look like this:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "eni1" {
    subnet_id        = "subnet-1234567"
    private_ips      = ["172.31.16.17"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "testec2instance" {
    ami             = "ami-12345678"
    instance_type   = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name        = "test-eni-attach-instance-01"
    }
    network_interface {
        device_index            = 0
        network_interface_id    = "${aws_network_interface.eni1.id}"
    }
}
```

If you only want to specify an exact IP address for your EC2 instance, you can use the private_ip argument in terraform while creating the instance.